# Rabbit MQ fault tolerance

Tags: rabbitmq, jms

I have a project where we are using Rabbit MQ has message broker, I have below concern, please help on the same.

1. If Rabbit MQ goes down, how we can retrieve the queued message.is there any configuration in rabbit MQ?
2. Can we implement same in java thread and collection combination, that can be used as alternative to rabbit MQ? if yes help with an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'You should listen to `ShutdownListener`callback on both `Connection` and `Channel`classes'. By this way, you know if the queue is down. After that, you need to re-transmit your queued messages. This is what official documentations says. https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html
2. Of course you can implement your own library, but you have to think if this would be better for you. I suggest you not to do that. RabbitMQ is a well-known open source library that many people use and trust for years. I think there is no side-effect using that in any project.

Comment: Thanks @M. Oğuz Özcan

Comment: If the answer worked for you could you please accept and vote for my answer? Thanks @AjeykumarHB

Answer (score 0):

Deploy RabbitMQ on Kubernetes with stateful sets. This will replicate state in multiple instances. One of them will be primary. Failover will be handled by Kubernetes.
See https://kublr.com/blog/reliable-fault-tolerant-messaging-rabbitmq-kublr/